# RTX 3080 - Deep Learning Training Problem: training stuck after "Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10"

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, nvidia

When 3D CNN training on NVIDIA GeForce **RTX 3080**, the training hangs after "**Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10**". When I run the same model on the **GTX 1650** with the same configurations of the computer, training is done without any problems. I am sharing the features of the system I use below.

- **Operating system:** Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS with NVIDIA drivers - 64 bit
- **System memory:** 32GB
- **Processor:** AMD® Ryzen 9 5980hs with radeon graphics × 16
- **Graphic Card:** NVIDIA Corporation GA104M [GeForce RTX 3080 Mobile / Max-Q 8GB/16GB] / NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080 Laptop GPU/PCIe/SSE2
- **Python version:** Python 3.9.7
- **Keras version:** 2.4.3
- **Tensorflow version:** 2.4.1
- **Driver Version:** 510.68.02
- **CUDA Version:** 11.6
- **Linux Kernel:** 5.15.23-76051523-generic

I am sharing the training process below.

```
2022-05-09 10:16:44.283512: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
Your tensorflow version is : 2.4
2022-05-09 10:17:02.344274: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc:41] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2022-05-09 10:17:02.345101: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2022-05-09 10:17:02.383373: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2022-05-09 10:17:02.384101: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080 Laptop GPU computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.545GHz coreCount: 48 deviceMemorySize: 15.75GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 417.29GiB/s
2022-05-09 10:17:02.384281: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2022-05-09 10:17:02.404397: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2022-05-09 10:17:02.404554: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublasLt.so.10
2022-05-09 10:17:02.416043: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2022-05-09 10:17:02.420146: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2022-05-09 10:17:02.439124: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2022-05-09 10:17:02.442663: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
2022-05-09 10:17:02.476159: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2022-05-09 10:17:02.476525: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2022-05-09 10:17:02.476905: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2022-05-09 10:17:02.476992: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1862] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
[INFO] Processing fold #0...
2022-05-09 10:17:02.678017: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2022-05-09 10:17:02.679390: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2022-05-09 10:17:02.679567: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080 Laptop GPU computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.545GHz coreCount: 48 deviceMemorySize: 15.75GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 417.29GiB/s
2022-05-09 10:17:02.679683: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2022-05-09 10:17:02.679718: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2022-05-09 10:17:02.679764: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublasLt.so.10
2022-05-09 10:17:02.679779: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2022-05-09 10:17:02.679804: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2022-05-09 10:17:02.679834: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2022-05-09 10:17:02.679854: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
2022-05-09 10:17:02.679877: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2022-05-09 10:17:02.680047: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2022-05-09 10:17:02.680411: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2022-05-09 10:17:02.680550: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1862] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2022-05-09 10:17:02.680953: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
```

What should I do to solve this problem?

PS: If you want more details, you can write to me.

Thank you so much.

Comment: I am also facing same problem

Answer (score 0):

I found this problem with myself there are some causes

1. Tensorflow and Keras version that is because I installed some components, they rolled back my Keras to old version.
2. The CuDa version does not match or target libraries does not include in the PATH or
3. It cannot register devices.